# Converting curl request and send file as part of payload in Golang

Tags: http, go, curl, request, http-post

I have a curl request that looks like this

```
curl -X POST https://kon-stage-ew1.pet.io/predict/pet-find/v1/predict \
  -H 'x-kon-Predict-Backend: https://kon-94fkr5wXRCeNu3IiDXzXFg-stage.cloud.pet.io' \
  -H 'x-analyzer-id: Feature:pet-find:Service-33f50d68d3db4fec9c75b73d3b83e016' \
  -H 'x-api-key: redStagekey' \
  -F 'properties={}' \
  -F content=@/Users/peter/Documents/01.jpg
```

The python http for this curl request looks like this

```
image1 = '01.jpg'
    headers = {
        'x-kon-Predict-Backend': 'https://kon-94fkr5wXRCeNu3IiDXzXFg-stage.cloud.pet.io',
        'x-analyzer-id': 'Feature:pet-find:Service-33f50d68d3db4fec9c75b73d3b83e016',
        'x-api-key': 'redStagekey',
    }

    payload = {'properties':'{}'}

    files = {
        'content':open(image1, 'rb')
    }

    response = requests.post('https://kon-stage-ew1.pet.io/predict/pet-find/v1/predict', headers=headers, data = payload, files=files)
    return response.content
```

I would like to convert this to equivalent Golang http request.
I tried several Golang libraries like grequests, http and also the blog post here https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013-07-golang-multipart-file-upload-example/
But none of them seem to work.
This is sample grequest that I tried

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/levigross/grequests"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

    url := "https://kon-stage-ew1.pet.io/predict/exposure-defect/v1/predict"

    headers := map[string]string{
        "x-kon-Predict-Backend": "https://kon-94fkr5wXRCeNu3IiDXzXFg-stage-eu-west-1.stage.cloud.pet.io",
        "x-analyzer-id": "Feature:pet-find:Service-33f50d68d3db4fec9c75b73d3b83e016",
        "x-api-key": "redStageKey",
    }

    payload := map[string]string{
        "properties":"{}",
    }

    file_upload, err := grequests.FileUploadFromDisk("/Users/akhikuma/Documents/01.jpg")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to open file: ", err)
    }

    ro := &grequests.RequestOptions{
        Headers: headers,
        Files: file_upload,
        Data: payload,
    }
    resp, err := grequests.Post(url,ro)

    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Println("Something wrong happened in post request: ", err)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)
    if resp.Ok != true {
        fmt.Println("Request did not return OK")
    }

}
```

This gives me following error

```
{"status_code": 400, "reason": "('Content data is missing. Check multipart file upload.', 400)"}
Request did not return OK
```

I also tried converting the curl request to golang using the postman but it is also not working since the request consists of uploading the file.

Note that in the python code I just don't send file but a dictionary of the file.
I tried converting the curl request using the postman to Golang but it not working since we also have to send the file as part of the payload.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should show your Go code and what didn't work. It seems this should not be too hard. Generating a multipart message is some work but reading a file and creating a POST request are pretty basic task as you see in the article you linked. Also: "it is not working" is not an actionable problem description: Please be much more specific.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Import function in Postman? It will have sample code for Golang

Comment: @SteveLam I tried postman import function but this is not working. It gives 500 Internal error even though curl request work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Volker I have added the sample go lang code and the response that I am getting from the server.

Comment: The issue is I dont know how to create a dictionary with `content` as key and file reader handle as value and pass that to http request in Go.
As you can see from the python code, I am able to create `files` which is a dictionary with `contents` as key and `open(image1, 'rb')` as value. Not sure how to do that in golang.

Comment: 1. Why are you using grequests? The very sensible article you linked does the same with  stdlib only.  2. Stop trying to port the Phyton code to Go, this will lead you nowhere, instead construct a proper HTTP request. 3. If you insist on using github.com/levigross/grequests: FileUploadFromDisk creates `FileUpload` which have field `FieldName` set that to content: `file_upload[0].FiledName="content". 4. If you use magic helper tools: Read and study their documentation in detail.

Comment: Thanks so much @Volker . This worked :)

Answer (score 0):

With the file in same directory of go file, try this piece of code.I encountered

`no such host error` but I think this will work.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    path, _ := os.Getwd()
    path += "/your/filename/here"

    url := "https://kon-stage-ew1.pet.io/predict/exposure-defect/v1/predict"

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("content", filepath.Base(path))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(part, file)

    err = writer.WriteField("properties", "{}")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    req.Header.Set("x-kon-Predict-Backend", "https://kon-94fkr5wXRCeNu3IiDXzXFg-stage-eu-west-1.stage.cloud.pet.io")
    req.Header.Set("x-analyzer-id", "Feature:pet-find:Service-33f50d68d3db4fec9c75b73d3b83e016")
    req.Header.Set("x-api-key", "redStageKey")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        body := &bytes.Buffer{}
        _, err := body.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(resp.Header)
        fmt.Println(body)
    }
}
```